# Parse .erb file and return Strings/Everything Within Ruby tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, erb

```
<h3>
  <% # This is fine %>
  <%= t("argument") %>
</h3>
<p>
  <%= "I need to return bad strings like this in ERB tags without method calls" %>
```

I'm parsing some html.erb files in RSpec to make sure that there are no random strings (I.E. <%= "Untranslated Word" %> to make sure that all strings are being passed through Rails' <%= t('string') %>. I don't want to use render : partial because I don't want to handle passing through Ruby variables as locals.

Could this be accomplished easily with a regex or some other built in ruby Method? Please note, I've tried a few Rubocop like tools like erb-lint and they don't quite fit my purposes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're using encoded strings as ruby tags, rather than just including them as text ...

Comment: Someone might use an ERB tag with some interpolation, <%= This is a string #{variable}" %>

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using a tool like Notepad++ or find or grep to find pattern what you don't want?
If you give me some information about you are using linux or windows I can give you a recommendation.

Search all your .erb files for pattern like `<%= "`?

Comment: can you edit your answer so that it is a practical answer? i.e. show examples using the "tool": `find app/views -type f -exec grep -l '%= "' {} \;`

Comment: I'm obviously looking for a tool to do it, hence why I posted here.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for tools are off topic on Stackoverflow. So I would really encourage you to be nice @zasman.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Questions%20asking%20us%20to%20recommend,attract%20opinionated%20answers%20and%20spam.&text=Instead%2C%20please%20direct%20your%20questions,company%2Forganisation's%20technical%20support%20team.

Comment: Dude, I'm not being rude. I'm not *necessarily* looking for a "tool" in the senses of a "library" but a "tool" in the sense of a solution or method, like a Ruby solution of how to parse. Maybe someone can suggest a regex method. And this dude was the one who was rude, he said "Why aren't you using a tool?" maybe I needed to specify in the original post that I've tried a few gems, because straight up saying "why are you not using a tool" is a worthless comment

Comment: did you already try the find command from @jad above?